# How to check if item of list is not dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to check if item of list is not dataframe.
My code is as below and this shows an error

```
list = [None, df1, df2, df3]

for n in list:
  if n != None:
    print(n)
```

> ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

is there any good solution?

Comment: Are you using Pandas? If so please add that tag to your question

Comment: yes, i am using pandas

Comment: The type you want to check for is `pd.DataFrame`

Comment: If you simply want to ensure it isn't None, `n is not None`.

Comment: Thanks all, your advices are very helpful

Answer (score 1):

```py
import pandas as pd

list = [None, df1, df2, df3]

for n in list:
  if type(n) is not pd.DataFrame:
    print(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

df1 = pd.DataFrame()

lst = [5, df1, 'jack']
for entry in lst:
    if not isinstance(entry, DataFrame):
        print(f'{entry} is not a df')
```

output

```
5 is not a df
jack is not a df
```